# XMLHttpRequest and JAX-RS 404 403 errors, can't get a response from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, xmlhttprequest, jax-rs, java-ee-7

Java EE is hell. I'm trying to implement a RESt service that is going to be queried by clients from arbitrary domain, using javascipt XMLHttpRequest.

For the server side, my context root is "qwerty". Then my resource class is:

```
@Path("test")
public class TestRest{

   @GET
    @Path("/{msg}")
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response answerBackToClient(@PathParam("msg") String message){

        Response.ResponseBuilder r;
        r = Response.ok();
        r = r.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        r = r.entity("responce back to client: " + message);

        return r.build();
    }

}
```

So from any browser anywhere now, with javascript:

```
     var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
     x.open("get", "http://www.pathtoserver.com:8080/qwerty/test/someMessage/", true);
     x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
     x.send("something");
```

Deployed on GlassFish4, EE7, NetBeans7.4

After i invoke the send() method on the client side (javascript), i get a 404 error or 403 error. What is the simplest possible example that will solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is that i can't get the response. From the client after i do .send(""), it says GET 404 (Not Found) or sometimes 403.

Comment: I believe the browser will send an OPTIONS request to the URL first, so you will likely need to provide an `@OPTIONS` annotated method that returns the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.